# How to pass a flavor in dependent project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to pass a flavor in the dependent common code.

```
include ':app', ':app_decouple'

include ':appcommon'
project(':appcommon').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../libs/appcommon')
```

for appcommon i want one specific flavor to build. How to achieve this?

Comment: any reason to downvote. if my question is not clear i can provide more details or what i am thinking.

Comment: You can't configure it in the settings.gradle but you can change the flavor for each module in your ide (feature on the bottom left).